# Need to save output of a GREP in a bash script as an integer

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I'm trying to get the occurrences of "(" in a variable and then use it in a loop

Tried:

```
LPC=$(grep -o "(" <<< $A  | wc -l)

while [ LPC -gt 0 ]; do
```

output:

```
line 53: [: LPC: integer expression expected
```

I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Damn. You're right. Doh! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the dollar sign before the variable.

Modify:

```
while [ LPC -gt 0 ]; do
```

to:

```
while [ $LPC -gt 0 ]; do
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform parameter substitution on LPC:

`while [ $LPC -gt 0 ]; do`